# are there any theories about required computing power propotional to quantity of object?

Tags: complexity-theory

If i want to calculate the movements of each moving objects driven by regular algorithm, then how to measure required computing power? Is required computing power proportional to the quantity of the objects? If so, how can i measure required computing power?

Comment: The question is underspecified. Try to give us more details.

Comment: To Yuval Filmus, Thank you, I found what I was finding, It's called "Big-O-notation"
after all it turned out that my question is trivial. and thank you for try to answer my question!